# Eclipse plugin development - extending ADT, how to make the plugin import existing project as library

Tags: eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-adt

I am developing an **Eclipse plugin extending ADT** (Android development tools).

I'd like to know how to make the plugin has the functions, "**import an existing project as library**" when the plugin is installed, and "when creating a project from my plugin, **the library is automatically being referenced**".

As far as I know, if you want to **make an existing project as a library**, you have to **import it into your workspace** and then **Properties -> Android -> Library -> "is Library"**. Then *Android tool* will update the `.properties` file as "`android.library=true`"

Then in the project that is using the library, **Properties -> Android -> Library** and then **Add** the library you just set. Then *Android tool* will update the `.properties` file as `android.library.reference.1=..\\theLibrary`.

But how can I do this automatically in my plugin?
How do I do "**import a project as a library**", "**update android project properties file**" in plugin?

I was thinking about extension point. But I don't know how to add an extension point to import a project and to manipulate Android tool.

Please help.

Comment: Your questions is a bit confusing, please remove some bold-usage in the text...
You are writing an Eclipse plugin. It depends on ADT. Now what do you want exactly?